# Find all positive sequneces $(s_n)_n$ such that: $\forall n\geq 1, \; \sum_{k=1}^n s_k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n s_k\right)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

The goal is to find all positive sequneces $(s_n)_n$ such that:
$$
\forall n\geq 1, \; \sum_{k=1}^n s_k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n s_k\right)^2.
$$
My attempt is the following: Let us consider a sequence $(s_n)_n$ satisfying:
$$
s_n>0, \; \sum_{k=1}^n s_k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n s_k\right)^2,
$$
for all $n\geq 1$. From the last equality we can remark:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n s_k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k+ s_n\right)^2= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k\right)^2+s_n^2 + 2s_n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k.
$$
This implies that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n s_k^3 =\underbrace{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k\right)^2}_{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k^3} +s_n^2 + 2s_n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k.
$$
So we get that
$$
s_n^3 - s_n^2 - 2s_n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k= 0 \implies s_n^2 - s_n -2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k = 0,
$$
since $s_n>0$. However I cannot find the sequences $(s_n)_n$ that satisfy the above equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We claim that $s_n=n$ is the only solution with $s_k>0$ for all $k$

Clearly $s_1=1$ by positivity and then $s_2^3+1=s_2^2+2s_2+1$ which gives $s_2^2=s_2+2$ so $s_2=2$ again by positivity; assume inductively $s_k=k, k\le n$ and then you get $s_{n+1}^3=s_{n+1}^2+(n^2+n)s_{n+1}$ since the free terms (as an equation in $s_{n+1}$) cancel out, hence by positivity again $s_{n+1}=n+1$ and we are done

Answer (score 4):

For $n=1$, one has $s_1^3=s_1^2$ which gives $s_1=1$. For $n=2$, one has
$$ s_1^3+s_2^3=(s_1+s_2)^2$$
which implies
$$ 1+s_2^3=1+2s_2+s_2^2$$
or
$$s_2(s_2+1)(s_2-2)=0.$$
Since $s_2>0$, one has $s_2=2$. Similarly, For $n=3$, one has
$$ s_1^3+s_2^3+s_3^2=(s_1+s_2+s_3)^2$$
which implies
$$ 9+s_2^3=9+6s_2+s_2^2$$
or
$$s_3(s_2+2)(s_2-3)=0 $$
Since $s_3>0$, one has $a_3=3$. Now one can guess $a_n=n$ and it should not be hard to use the Mathematical Induction to prove it.

Update: it is true
$$ \sum_{k=1}^nk^3=(\sum_{k=1}^nk)^2. $$